# How can I make my Express use an independent user's rate instead of the server itself?

Tags: node.js, express

I currently have an ***Express*** app running as a back end hosted on [***onRender***](https://render.com/) for free that serves API for my front end. The ***Express*** is using another third-party extension to get the data. And their rate limit is 90 requests per minute for every user. (I'm getting images and descriptions, etc. and they allow it for non-commercial purposes). I made the site as a hobby project and for free for me and a couple of my friends to use, so the traffic of use might go over 90 rates per minute for the server itself, but that'll not be the case if I can somehow make my app use user rate independently, mean 90 requests per minute for each user independently.

This is their rate limit policy: [Anilist rate limit  policy](https://anilist.gitbook.io/anilist-apiv2-docs/overview/rate-limiting)

I'm using this npm to get their data: [Anilist node extension](https://www.npmjs.com/package/anilist-node)

But I think that whenever someone uses my app in the front end that connects to the back end, the third-party extension counts my Express server as 1 user only.

Because: User goes to my page => API from my Express come to serve => Express itself has its own domain and counts as only 1 due to it having its own IP address.

So 90 requests, but if 10 people use my app, each of them will only have 9 requests per minute, what if later on there are 90 people using my app, if so, each person will only have 1 request?

Please correct me if my way of thinking is wrong.

If I'm not wrong, is there anyways I can make my user use their own rate instead of the server's rate itself?

This is how I set up my Express (I minify it a bit, but the whole Express app is following this structure).

My tree structure is only like this:

```
.
└── Express root folder/
    └── src/
        ├── model.js
        ├── routes.js
        ├── controller.js
        └── index.js
```

This is my `index.js` and how I set up Express file:

```
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")
const path = require("path")
const routes = require("./routes")
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(cors())
app.set("trust proxy", true)

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    )
    next()
})
app.use("/api", routes)
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server is running", PORT)
})
```

In the `routes.js` file I config it like this:

```
const express = require("express")
const controller = require("./controller")
const router = express.Router()

router.get("/", controller.getData)
module.exports = router
```

How I set up my controller:

```
const Model = require("./model")
class Controller {
    static async getData(req, res, next) {
        try {
            const data = await Model.getData()
            res.json({ success: true, data  })
        } catch (err) {
            res
                .status(404)
                .send({ success: false, data: "Fail and get 404" })
        }
    }
  }
module.exports = Controller
```

My `model.js`:

```
const anilist = require("anilist-node")
const Anilist = new anilist() <==== extension I use to get data, or it could be any other extension
class Model {
    static async getData() {

        //DOING SOMETHING WITH THE ANILIST EXTENSION WILL COUNT THE SERVER RATE, NOT USER RATE

        return data
    }
}
module.exports = Model
```